# How does one change the key used to sign an android application that is already on the play store?

Tags: android, google-play

In the event of a security breach, if an intruder manages to make a copy of a key used to sign the app (as well as the password), then how does one revoke the key, and assign a new one ?

Is this even possible (to revoke the key) ?

Comment: I think you would have to unpublish the app, sign it with a new key and republish it.

Comment: I can't find this in the documentation - where did you read it ? I imagine that the app package name would have to be changed, in which case no one who has downloaded the app already will get updates, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: There is a "Warning" that talks about it. http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#release-mode

Answer (score 0):

Thats really a good question. Google just says that you have to save the key properly.

If you have to re-sign your apk File with a different key there is no other solution than:

- unpublishing the app
- use a new package name
- and the new key
- publish the new app

I also dont like this solution, but as far as I know it is the only one. I had the same problem some months ago.

Comment: If the app package name would have to be changed, no one who has downloaded the app already will get updates, which defeats the purpose. Its equivalent to publishing an entirely new app with the same name.

Comment: I agree... but I dont see any other possibility as Google seems to be quite strict on this. And as far as I know you cannot upload an App with the same package name...